# Arrows between Young tableaux

Tags: tables, arrows

I am working with some tableaux-like objects (standard and semistandard Young tableaux) and want to illustrate certain mappings on these objects. I would like to do this by drawing arrows between different tableaux but cannot seem to figure out how to make the arrows look good. The arrows are always up aligned and I would like to be able to adjust them vertically so they start from the middle of the tableaux.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \ytableaushort{1235,235,34,45,5} \longrightarrow \ytableaushort{1124,2335,44,5} \longrightarrow \ytableaushort{1125,344,45} \longrightarrow
    \ytableaushort{11}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: changed from align to equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where do you want the arrows to be? And why do you use an align environment if you do not use alignment points?

Comment: The align environment was just a mistake on my part, I have now edited it into the equation environment, although the problem is still there.

I would like the arrow to go from the middle (vertically) of the left diagram to the middle of the right diagram. At the moment, it is going from the top of each diagram to the top of the next diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this befit you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\ytableausetup{aligntableaux =top, nobaseline}
\begin{equation*}
    \ytableaushort{1235,235,34,45, 5 } \raisebox{1.1ex}{${}\longrightarrow{}$} \ytableaushort{1124,2335,44,5} \raisebox{1.1ex}{${}\longrightarrow{}$}\ytableaushort{1125,344,45} \raisebox{1.1ex}{${}\longrightarrow{}$}
    \ytableaushort{11}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes. After changing from "aligntableaux =top" to "aligntableaux =center", this did want I wanted.

Comment: Actually, I obtain the same result without  the setup line (that is, with the defaults).

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but I wanted the arrows to be center aligned. It seems that by default and by your code, the arrow gets top aligned.

Comment: I aligned the arrows more or less with the centre of the top row. In my opinion, centre-aligned arrows is meaningless since all tableaux have a different number of rows. Unless I misunderstand what you want?